# Creating Array Variable in Snowflake from JSON String

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to create a variable in Snowflake that I can reference in a table query.

example:

```
-- Desired variable. I can't actually do this since parse_json isn't a constant source expression
set my_arr = parse_json('["Hello", "world"]');
```

I want to use it like:

```
select
    *
from
    my_tbl
where
    word in $my_arr
;
```

How could I go about creating essentially an array that I can reference in a where clause query? I'd rather not have to run multiple table where clauses that reference a potentially large array of strings each time, when I could just store it in an array result globally and reference it in a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a lookup table instead.

```
create or replace temporary table lookup as
select value as word 
from table(flatten(['Hello', 'world'])) --supply your words here

select *
from your_table a
where exists (select * from lookup b where a.word=b.word)
```

You can also tweak it to do wildcard matches by either supplying wildcards to `flatten` or by concatenating wildcard character later on, like so.

```
select *
from your_table a
where exists (select * from lookup b where a.word ilike '%'||b.word||'%')
```

Another option is to convert array to a string and do a regex exact match

```
set word= (select array_to_string(['Hello','World'],'|'));

select *
from your_table 
where word rlike $word
```

Comment: This seems like a sensible solution for sure. I was just wondering if there was a way to work with an array variable like a traditional programming language.

Comment: @Coldchain9 I added in a hack that I am not particularly proud of but might do the job

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the result you are looking for using the var ( var defined as a string)

````
set my_arr = '["Hello", "world"]';

select f.value::text  
from my_tbl, lateral flatten(input => parse_json($my_arr)) f
where word= f.value::text;
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Using `ARRAY_CONTAINS`:

```
set my_arr = '["Hello", "world"]';

select   *
from my_tbl
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(word::VARIANT, PARSE_JSON($my_arr));
```

It is worth noting: [Initializing Variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables#initializing-variables)

> Variables can be set by executing the SQL statement **SET** or by setting the variables in the connection string when you connect to Snowflake.
>
> **The size of string or binary variables is limited to 256 bytes**.